# Why is it not standardized that an exception object is moved to a catch-clause object when catching the exception by value in case it is not elided?

Tags: c++, exception

In a throw-expression if the compiler cannot perform copy elision but the conditions for copy elision are met or would be met, except that the source is a function parameter, the compiler will attempt to use the move constructor even if the object is designated by an lvalue;

In a catch clause, the following is permitted: when the argument is of the same type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the exception object thrown, the copy of the exception object is omitted and the body of the catch clause accesses the exception object directly, as if caught by reference. This is disabled if such copy elision would change the observable behavior of the program for any reason other than skipping the copy constructor and the destructor of the catch clause argument (for example, if the catch clause argument is modified, and the exception object is rethrown with throw).

In my view, it would be a reasonable solution to perform moving to the catch-clause argument if the conditions for this copy elision are met, but it is not performable by the compiler.

Since it is only for the cases when the copy elision is safe, it is completely safe too (e.g., does not prevent optimal implementation of rethrowing the exception).

Why is not it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy elision in a throw-expression, as any other feature, needs to be implemented before it is available.

Moving itself (regardless exceptions) is a must feature of the language, the cost of not supporting this feature would be unforgivable.

Applying this already existing feature, moving, in the specified way in the throw-expression is much easier than implementing the copy elision.

The specified conditions are quite natural for moving and there is not a lot of additional work both by compiler engineers to implement and of compilers to perform it in run-time.

But implementing copy elision there requires more substantial additional work by the engineers and more substantially complicates compiling algorithms.

So, it is allowed for compilers to be simpler by the cost of not supporting some copy elision for some or all of the circumstances.

---

In a catch clause, the only difficulty for copy elision is meeting the conditions, the copy elision itself is quite simply implementable there. And still the conditions are the same for copy elision and moving there, implementation difficulties are about the same too.

But copy elision is obviously more efficient than moving.

So there is just no reason to load compiler engineers and compilers with the moving feature there.